# asp.net - Web API 2 Singe Page Application - Using built in Login form doesn't authorize?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, authorize

I'm just working on my first Web API 2 Single Page Application in Visual Studio 2013. When I started with the project I chose Authentication: Individual Accounts. So when I build the solution, the login form appeared. I registered a user and I can successfully log in.

My controller is ready to use and I put the `[authorize]-Attribute` in front of my requests.

When I'm not logged in and navigate to my request, it shows me the error-message:

```
"Authorization has been denied for this request."
```

That's great, but when I'm logged in and navigate to the request again, it still shows me the same message.

The controller itself is working fine without the `[authorize]-attribute`.

I'm really new to this topic and I couldn't find anything about how to connect the built in Login with authorizing my requests. I hope, you can help me.

EDIT:

I just found out about the differences of Authentication and Authorization. First is for identifying the user, second is for giving him rights to do anything...

So I tried `[Authorize(Users="Username")]`, but it doesn't work. (It should work with `[Authorize]` as well, because therefore you authorize all users??)

What's wrong with my application? :(

EDIT 2:

I'm still searching for how to get the access_token into the header! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When You are sending Request To your controller through ajax add your authorization claims token

For every request you need to send authorization token

In your login.viewmodel.js of SPA after user successfully logged in you are saving data.access_token,this token needs to send for every ajax request as below

If this answered your question, Please check right on left side.

```
  $.ajax(url, {
                type: "POST",
                data: data,
                headers: "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
            });




  dataModel.login({
            grant_type: "password",
            username: self.userName(),
            password: self.password()
        }).done(function (data) {
            self.loggingIn(false);

            if (data.userName && data.access_token) {
                app.navigateToLoggedIn(data.userName, data.access_token, self.rememberMe());
            } else {
                self.errors.push("An unknown error occurred.");
            }
        }).failJSON(function (data) {
            self.loggingIn(false);

            if (data && data.error_description) {
                self.errors.push(data.error_description);
            } else {
                self.errors.push("An unknown error occurred.");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Now I understand the whole thing, but there is one question left to get it working. I hope it's not stupid, but how can I get the accessToken to my ajax-request? I tried several possibilities, but it's always undefined.

Comment: getSecurityHeaders() returns your access token , so call this method if you changed login functionality save your auth token in some vairable or cookie or localstorage and call that  localStorage["accessToken"] = accessToken;

Comment: That's it! :) I just added headers: getSecurityHeaders() and now it works! I just wonder, why I couldn't find anything on the internet about this! Thank you so much! :)